# Controlling Activity visible area when using adjustPan

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I've been using `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustResize"` in one of my `Activity`'s configurations. But,it lacks in performance. So, after exploring, I came across another parameter `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan"`. It's better in performance, but have one issue. My whole layout is scroll upward. My layout contains a custom title view at top, which I don't want to be scrolled. Is there a way to control the area of a layout to be scrolled when using `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan"`?

[image]

Layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" Title Bar "
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="#cacaca"/>


    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```